Is GPU memory coalescing something the hardware does or the programmer does?
I am learning about memory coalescing in NVIDIA GPUs. I am trying to understand what exactly coalescing is. More specifically, is it something specifically implemented by hardware, or is it just the act––done by the programmer––of making different threads access consecutive memory addresses?
I have consulted several sources but they all give contradictory answers:
This article implies coalescing is something explicitly done by the hardware, which makes me believe that if coalescing wasn't implemented by the hardware, then even if the programmer makes it such that, for example, 5 different threads all access 5 different addresses that are in the same block (unit of data transfer between the global memory and cache), they would incur a total of 5 data transfers instead of 1 transfer and 4 cache hits.
This CS StackExchange answer seems to imply it is a programming principle. That is, coalescing is simply making sure each thread accesses consecutive addresses instead of addresses spaced far apart.
I am, in particular, comparing memory coalescing to cache hits in CPU memory accesses, in which the first access to an address in a block incurs a cache miss and subsequent accesses to other addresses in the same block all incur a cache hit in a reasonable amount of time. We don't call the CPU version coalescing, so how is this different from GPU memory coalescing? This feels more akin to the idea of locality, which is not really a hardware implemented feature but simply the practice of making sure your data accesses are close.
Perhaps if helps to ask, what happens if GPU didn't do coalescing? Would accesses to consecutive memory addresses in the same block at the same time by different threads really incur multiple transfers if no coalescing was done? I feel like it won't, because of the already-there granularity of data transfers; i.e., it is already part of the hardware architecture.

It's cooperation:

programmer should access memory in the described pattern
and then GPU combines these accesses

GPUs also implement caching. Coalescing is a different mechanism — it combines accesses from the same instruction executed in the same warp. The key point is that GPUs are really SIMD processors, and they can combine memory accesses from the single SIMD instruction into a larger access. CPUs can't do that.

Is it correct to say that if coalescing wasn't specifically implemented on GPUs, then simultaneous accesses to the same block by threads in a warp would trigger multiple accesses? And that this is bad because, even if these accesses are done in parallel, they would occupy more memory bandwidth?

"Modern" CPU's also have SIMD instructions (e.g. SSE and AVX on x86). These can also do "gather" operations to combine multiple memory accesses from a single SIMD instruction.
